# How do I create Shopify metafields specific to product types?

Tags: shopify

I am using a Shopify 2.0 theme that supports standard Shopify metafields.

I can easily create product metafields that appear correctly on each product listing page in admin.

Can I create different sets of metafileds to attach to specific product types? Or am I expecting too much from the standard Shopify metafield functionality?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can define metafields for a specific product types.
But can't you just leave the metafield blank on the product types you don't need them for? And then in the theme only display the metafield is exists `!= blank`